# Why FFT of a rectangular pulse has imaginary part while the sinc function is real?

Tags: fft

I have a rectangular pulse:

```
w = 20; pln = 10;
v =[zeros(1, pln), ones(1, w),zeros(1, pln)];
figure(); plot(v,'-o');
```

by perform `fft` and `fftshift` the pulse center to zero to get its frequency domain representation:

```
yf = fftshift(fft(v));
xf = [-0.5000   -0.4750   -0.4500   -0.4250   -0.4000   -0.3750   -0.3500   -0.3250...
-0.3000   -0.2750   -0.2500   -0.2250   -0.2000   -0.1750   -0.1500   -0.1250...
-0.1000   -0.0750   -0.0500   -0.0250         0    0.0250    0.0500    0.0750...
0.1000    0.1250    0.1500    0.1750    0.2000    0.2250    0.2500    0.2750...
0.3000    0.3250    0.3500    0.3750    0.4000    0.4250    0.4500    0.4750];
yf = yf.*exp(-2j*pi*xf*(pln+w/2)); % this shifts the time domain signal to zero
```

`yf` is close to the sinc function - the Fourier transform of a rectangular function - but not exactly the same, it has imaginary part while sinc is is purely real:

```
yf_sinc = w*sinc(w*xf);
```

Why is the difference and why `ifft` of samples taken from a sinc function will not produce an exact rectangular pulse but with ripples close to the edge while `ifft(fft(v))` will exactly reproduce the original rectangular pulse:

```
% has ripples around the edges
figure(); plot(fftshift(ifft(fftshift(yf_sinc)))); 
% reproduces the exact rectangular pulse  
figure(); plot(fftshift(ifft(fftshift(yf))));
```

herer `yf`, if we assume it was directly sampled form a underlying function, that is ingoring the fact that it is produced by `fft` of a rectangular pulse (it's just some numbers anyway), what function would it be? Is it possible by sampling a function in the frequency domain (not need to be the sinc function) and take the `ifft` will produce an exact rectangular pulse?

[image: rectangular pulse and fft compared to a sinc function sampes]

Comment: To get a purely real output, your signal needs to be "DFT-even" symmetrical, which basically means it has one extra sample at the beginning. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]` is DFT-even symmetrical, for instance.  (and the DFT bins are symmetrical in the same way, starting at DC: `[DC, 1, 2, fs/2, 2, 1]`)

Comment: The answer to a question that is nearly identical to your question is: 
  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32216/should-the-phase-coefficients-of-the-dft-of-a-real-even-input-signal-all-be-zer

Answer (score 3):

The even part of a real signal transforms to the real part of the DFT.  The odd part of a real signal transforms to the imaginary part of the DFT.  For example, the DFT of cosine, an even function, is strictly real, while the DFT of a sine, an odd function, is strictly imaginary.

Answer (score 3):

To get a purely real output, your signal needs to be "DFT-even" symmetrical, which basically means it has one extra sample at the beginning.  For instance:

- `[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]` is "normal" even symmetrical
- `[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]` is DFT-even symmetrical

So this rectangular pulse FFT has an imaginary part:

```
fft([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
Out[7]: 
array([ 4.0+0.j   , -1.5-0.866j, -0.5-0.866j,  0.0-0.j   , -0.5+0.866j,
       -1.5+0.866j])
```

but this rectangular pulse FFT does not:

```
fft([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
Out[8]: array([ 3.+0.j, -2.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  1.-0.j,  0.+0.j, -2.+0.j])
```

As you can see, the DFT output is also DFT-even symmetrical

```
[3, -2, 0, 1, 0, -2]
     │  └─────┘   │
     └────────────┘
```

as are the frequency bins themselves:

```
[DC, fs/6, fs/3, -fs/2, -fs/3, -fs/6]
      │     └─────────────┘      │
      └──────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not symmetrical around index 0 (supposedly the first index).  You probably need to apply `fftshift` before the transform as well as afterwards in order to get the representation you expect both in time and frequency domain.